# Car memory recovery after battery removal

Tags: battery, car, memory

Is there a way of recovering car memory(radio,time) after forgetting to use a memory saver?

Comment: You can connect a smaller battery to maintain your memory and settings when you swap your main battery. Sounds like it's too late for that though...

Comment: Can you provide: Year make and model of vehicle, or make and model of stereo head unit if it's aftermarket.

Answer (score 2):

Usually not. When a component relies on volatile memory to store settings it's often because the manufacturer wanted to cut costs by not including permanent storage. Once the data's gone, it's gone for good.

Answer (score 1):

No.

The memory used to store the radio stations is volatile, and once the battery is removed, the data is gone.

May be, some radios have a power  buffer to keep the data for a short period, or they have non-volatile memory.  But in this case, the stations would just be there, and you don't have to recover them somehow.

For the clock, it's the same.

Comment: Fwiw my head unit accepts a cr2032 in a slot in the back for these occasions. Point being some also have batteries for backup, in addition to the possibilities  listed here.